# How to avoid repeating adding elements to a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, file

How can I add unique file paths to the `groups_of_files` list while avoiding duplication due to the cycles in my loop?

```
for file in files_names:
for name_group, formats in groups_of_format.items():
    if file.split('.')[-1].upper() in groups_of_format.values():
        groups_of_files[groups_of_format.keys()].append(file)
```

Comment: With the "in" operator you can test if an item is contained in a list already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sets instead of lists. Elements in sets are kept unique using an hash.

Something like:

```
groups_of_files = defaultdict(set)
for file in files_names:
  for name_group, formats in groups_of_format.items():
    if file.split('.')[-1].upper() in groups_of_format.values():
      groups_of_files[groups_of_format.keys()].add(file)
```

I assumed that `groups_of_files` is a dictionary. In the code example, when the element of the dictionary is missing, instead of raising exceptions, the element is created and the value is an empty set to which you can add your `file`. If `file` is of a custom type, make sure to define the `__hash__` and the `__eq__` methods.

If in the end you need anyway a list, you can convert a set to a list just using `list()` and the set as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set to keep track of the files that have already been added to the groups_of_files list.

```js
added_files = set()
for file in files_names:
    for name_group, formats in groups_of_format.items():
        if file.split('.')[-1].upper() in formats and file not in added_files:
            groups_of_files[name_group].append(file)
            added_files.add(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a dictionary keyed on the filename extensions. Associated values should be a set.

Subsequently, build the required dictionary by converting the sets to lists as follows:

```
import os

temp = dict()

files_names = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.py', 'e.txt', 'f.py']

for file in files_names:
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    temp.setdefault(ext.upper()[1:], set()).add(file)

groups_of_files = {k: list(v) for k, v in temp.items()}

print(groups_of_files)
```

**Output:**

```
{'TXT': ['e.txt', 'b.txt', 'a.txt'], 'PY': ['c.py', 'f.py']}
```